# How can I return a column value in postgresql when inserting into the table?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of in the format

```
    userid uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 (),
    username VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    password_salt VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    creation_date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I insert into the table, I a uuid is generated.  How can I retrieve the uuid generated from an insert command without sending another select query?  The best I have is something like this:

```
INSERT into user (username, email, password, salt) VALUES ('user', 'email', 'password', 'salt') 
RETURNING uuid;
```

but it doesn't work because it doesn't know what the uuid variable I am referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return the column name not a data type:

```
insert into user (username, email, password, salt) 
      values ('user', 'email', 'password', 'salt') 
returning userid;
```